# VideoPlayer kivymd python

Tags: python, kivy, media-player, kivy-language

How to use "VideoPlayer" widget to create "segment-player"?

For example: I have 10 segments: seg-1.mp4, seg2.mp4... seg10.mp4. How to create video player, as in sites, which allows play video by segments.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to archive that, would to inherit the Videoplayer that has direct access to the kivy.core.video widget.

Then from reading the source you could try to have the video on the RAM (as a file object) and parse it down to the video widget.
The video on the RAM could be an empty video file where you append the streams you have saved and as the video plays, the stream is shown in the video widget. But it's rather complex.

Or you could do a sub routine that reloads the source every segment of the video in the order you wish with an event driven sequence. Instead of changing the videoplayer source, you would be changing the _video widget inside the player. And remember to change the video config to autoplay so the load times would be shorter between segments.